# AppStore In-App-Purchase: How to get the currency a user will pay in?

Tags: localization, in-app-purchase, app-store

I have an iOS app using In-App-Purchase that caters to an international audience, so I expect payments in different currencies (USD, EUR, CNY, ... you know them from the AppStore Pricing Matrix). Of course I would like to show the items for purchase with the user's local currency, but I don't really know how.

Using the region or language of a user seems like a bad indicator, as the currency depends on the region of the AppStore account the user is using and not on the device settings.

How can I find out which currency a user will pay in?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Once you have SKProduct object fetched you can construct its localized price from price and priceLocale properties. Here's copy-paste from [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKProduct_Reference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008414-CH1-SW3) how to do that:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSNumberFormatterBehavior10_4];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[numberFormatter setLocale:product.priceLocale];
NSString *formattedString = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:product.price];
```

Comment: So I shouldn't have the items for sale in my app directly, but request them from apple to get the localized values and texts. Right?

Comment: Yes, per Apple guidelines you should store purchase items ids in application and then fetch SKProduct items from apple sever (e.g. see skproductsrequest class). That approach will also ensure that you present to users only those items that are approved by apple and valid for purchase

Comment: I used these code in my app, but why it always shows USD. I tried to change Language Setting on my iPhone, but didn't work. What's wrong with it?

Comment: @iOS.dev I think it depends on the region of the App Store account, so you may want to create different App Store accounts that belong to different countries.

Comment: @s1u Did you solve this? I also always get USD, but my system locale has EUR set as currency.

Comment: @ErikAigner as Joe mentioned, the local currency you're gonna see affiliates with the iTunes account that you signed in, instead of system language and region.

Comment: @s1u not true. I'm signed into the Austrian store, still I get USD instead of EUR.

Comment: Getting the *local* price is simple enough using this answer, but I'm curious if there's a way to get the *USD* price, regardless of the user's current store.  (I wish to alter the thank-you message based on how many 99¢-s were spent.)  Can you update your answer to show how to always get the USD price?  Thanks!

Comment: @Olie, I afraid there's no way to do that using apple's SDK.